# Elegant check for -1 in Python

Tags: python, string

Is there an elegant way to check for the value -1 as returned by the `str.find()` instance method ? I find testing for a value of -1 very ugly but I don't want to say < 0 either as that could cause confusion.

```
if (myString.find('foo') == -1):
    print("foo not found in ", myString)
```

Comment: I wonder if `== -1` or `< 0` is better optimized at the processor level. If the processor is smart, then `< 0` only requires checking one bit, which is pretty darn fast. It's been too long since my computer architecture classes, though.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: This is Python, not C; `-1` and `0` are objects, which in the case of CPython, happen to be interned (all small integers between -1 and 255 are) and all Python has to do is test for pointer equality when using `==`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I hadn't considered that. All of my C learning is coming back to bite me working with Python. I need to retrain my brain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use `str.find()` if you don't need the index. Use `in` to test for the substring instead; or in this case `not in` to negate the test:

```
if 'foo' not in myString:
    print("foo not found in", myString)
```

Comment: Thanks, I somehow didn't know 'in' existed!

Answer (score 3):

For reference, in cases where you do need the index, there is another string instance method for finding it: [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index).

The difference between `str.index` and `str.find` is that `str.index` will `raise ValueError` if the substring isn't found, which may be more appropriate for your use case (e.g. if you expect that the substring will generally be present):

```
try:
    index = myString.index("foo")
except ValueError:
    print("'foo' not found in '{0}'.".format(myString))
else:
    # 'foo' was found, 'index' has been assigned
```